# if the check box is within a ListView how to implement the OnCheckedChangeListener

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I succeed to display Phone Contacts in a check Box within a ListView but if I click the button a can't check which check box is checked 
this a is the code I work with ----->

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
  import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
  import android.view.Window;
   import android.view.WindowManager;
   import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
 import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
 import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Secure1 extends Activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener{



CheckBox ch1;
public static final String TAG = "ContactManager";

private Button bSave;
private ListView lv;
private boolean mShowInvisible;
CheckBox ch;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.v(TAG, "Activity State: onCreate()");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main1);
    bSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addContactButton);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactList);
    ch = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.contactEntryText);        
    bSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Log.d(TAG, "mAddAccountButton clicked");
            //launchContactAdder();
        }
    });

    populateContactList();
}
private void populateContactList() {
    // Build adapter with contact entries
    Cursor cursor = getContacts();
    String[] fields = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME
    };
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new 
  SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.contact_entry  , cursor,   
  fields, new int[] {R.id.contactEntryText});
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
 }

 private Cursor getContacts(){
        // Run query
        Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection = new String[] {
                ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
        };
        String selection = null;
        String[] selectionArgs = null;
        String sortOrder =null

        return managedQuery(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
    }
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
     TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast text = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wa3333333",
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);     
}
     }
```

and the layout i work with are :

main1.xml ---->

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <ListView android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:id="@+id/contactList"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"/>

  <Button android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/addContactButton"
        android:text="save"/>
   </LinearLayout>
```

et aussi contact_entry.xml---->

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">


  <CheckBox 
    android:text="@+id/contactEntryText"
          android:id="@+id/contactEntryText"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    />
   </LinearLayout>
```

I want if I check one of those check boxes something happen like Toast ..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a viewHolder which is usually the best way of doing
http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html
or the pdf
http://dl.google.com/googleio/2010/android-world-of-listview-android.pdf

So you are using a viewHolder which contains a checkbox. When overriding the getView method you'll do something like :

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View aView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = null;
    if (aView == null) {
        ...
        viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.MyCheckbox);
        viewHolder.checkbox
             .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()                  
                 {
                  @Override
                  public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                          boolean isChecked) {
                      ...
                  }
              });
         ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
     ...
    return view;
}
```

}

I did not write the rest of the required code as you were only asking for the implementation of the oncheckchangelistener.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

add `android:onClick="onCheckedChanged"` to the checkboxes in xml.

Comment: how will we pass the postion of the row whose checkbox is clicked to this eventHandler?